# Can't validate certificate - TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I am trying to establish secure communication with remote server, which is unfortunately signed by their own certification authority. I read official android docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html and it is written here, that when certification authority is not in android list, you need to accept server certificate by yourself. SO I did it like this (again from docs):

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificate);
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);


HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out);
```

But it is NOT working, I am getting error:

```
10-10 09:48:17.320: W/System.err(27787): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.
10-10 09:48:17.350: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:401)
10-10 09:48:17.350: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
10-10 09:48:17.350: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
10-10 09:48:17.350: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
10-10 09:48:17.350: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
10-10 09:48:17.370: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
10-10 09:48:17.400: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
10-10 09:48:17.400: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
10-10 09:48:17.400: W/System.err(27787):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
10-10 09:48:17.400: W/System.err(27787):    at com.myapp..webservice.RequestConfigurationAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestConfigurationAsyncTask.java:36)
10-10 09:48:17.411: W/System.err(27787):    at com.myapp..webservice.RequestConfigurationAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestConfigurationAsyncTask.java:1)
10-10 09:48:17.411: W/System.err(27787):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-10 09:48:17.441: W/System.err(27787):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-10 09:48:17.441: W/System.err(27787):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-10 09:48:17.441: W/System.err(27787):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-10 09:48:17.441: W/System.err(27787):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-10 09:48:17.441: W/System.err(27787):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-10 09:48:17.461: W/System.err(27787): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.
10-10 09:48:17.461: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:308)
10-10 09:48:17.461: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
10-10 09:48:17.471: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:595)
10-10 09:48:17.471: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
10-10 09:48:17.471: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:398)
10-10 09:48:17.471: W/System.err(27787):    ... 16 more
10-10 09:48:17.471: W/System.err(27787): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.
10-10 09:48:17.511: W/System.err(27787):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:122)
10-10 09:48:17.511: W/System.err(27787):    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:190)
10-10 09:48:17.571: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:295)
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787):    ... 20 more
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787): Caused by: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.AnnotatedException: TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed.
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.findTrustAnchor(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:235)
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:117)
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787):    ... 22 more
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787): Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature was not verified
10-10 09:48:17.591: W/System.err(27787):    at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:384)
10-10 09:48:17.601: W/System.err(27787):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.verifyX509Certificate(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:1427)
10-10 09:48:17.621: W/System.err(27787):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.findTrustAnchor(CertPathValidatorUtilities.java:222)
10-10 09:48:17.621: W/System.err(27787):    ... 23 more
```

Why I am getting **TrustAnchor found but certificate validation failed**? Looks like certificate was loaded, but it is not correct or valid or so - but I downloaded certificate of page through web browser (in both crt, pem format but nothing worked) so it should work. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you check your min SDK and Target SDK?

Comment: min is 14, target is 19...Why?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 reasons for this please look at following link

The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown
The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed
The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA

**https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html**

Comment: I know it, it's written in docs. But I do not know how to fix it...Maybe I should create my own TrustManager and manually accept/refuse certificate how I want...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in normal java application and not in android.

Security.insertProviderAt(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);